# Error ";",, expected after variable declaration

Tags: java, quadratic

Syntax error ";",, expected on line "double a, b, c, discriminant, root;"

How do I resolve this error?

```
public class Quadratic {

    double a, b, c, discriminant, root;

    discriminant = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;

    public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
    }

    public String calculateroots() {

        if (discriminant >= 0){
            root = Math.sqrt(discriminant) / (2 * a);

            System.out.println("Your roots are " + (-1 * b) + "+" + root + "and" + (-1 * b) + (-1 * root) +".");
        }
        else {
            root = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

            System.out.println("Your roots are " + (-1 * b) + "+ i" + root + "and" + (-1 * b) + "i" + (-1 * root) +".");
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: there are several issues with that code. starting with: discriminant = (b * b) - 4 * a * c; needs to be in a method or an initialization block

Comment: Hint: please read about Java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase! And then: read about java syntax. You can't put statements just where you think they might fit ...

Comment: I suggest in the Constructor, setting your instance variables, and then solving the discriminant there. `public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) { this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; discriminant = (b*b)-4 * a * c; }`

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for variables initializations in the constructor as `discriminant` initialization in the `calculateroots`.

```
   public class Quadratic {

        double a, b, c, discriminant, root;

        public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void calculateroots() {
            discriminant = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;

            if (discriminant >= 0){
                root = Math.sqrt(discriminant) / (2 * a);

                System.out.println("Your roots are " + (-1 * b) + "+" + root + "and" + (-1 * b) + (-1 * root) +".");
            }
            else {
                root = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

                System.out.println("Your roots are " + (-1 * b) + "+ i" + root + "and" + (-1 * b) + "i" + (-1 * root) +".");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
public class Quadratic {

    double a, b, c, discriminant, root;

    public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
        discriminant = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;
    }

    public void calculateroots() {

        if (discriminant >= 0) {
            root = Math.sqrt(discriminant) / (2 * a);

            System.out.println("Your roots are " + (-1 * b) + "+" + root + "and" + (-1 * b) + (-1 * root) + ".");
        } else {
            root = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

            System.out.println("Your roots are " + (-1 * b) + "+ i" + root + "and" + (-1 * b) + "i" + (-1 * root) + ".");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First: Code only answers are bad. Second: Don't you think it would make sense to initialize `a`, `b` and `c`, as well?

Answer (score -1):

to just answer your question... the syntax error is caused by the location of

`discriminant = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;`

discriminant is assigned `(a, b ,c)` uninitialized variables.

I suggest moving it into `calculateroots()` and change the return type to void as:

```
public class Quadratic {

    double a, b, c, discriminant, root;

    public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a; 
        this.b = b; 
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void calculateroots() {

        discriminant = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;

        if (discriminant >= 0){
            root = Math.sqrt(discriminant) / (2 * a);

            System.out.println("Your roots are " + (-1 * b) + "+" + root + "and" + (-1 * b) + (-1 * root) +".");
        }
        else {
            root = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

            System.out.println("Your roots are " + (-1 * b) + "+ i" + root + "and" + (-1 * b) + "i" + (-1 * root) +".");
        }
        }
    }
```

and this way you create just instance of Quadratic and give values to the constructor for `a`, `b` and `c` then call `calculateroots()`

Comment: NO ! it's not becoz of "**discriminant is assigned (a, b ,c) uninitialized variables.**"

Comment: NO! I m not ,because If u write something like double myvar=a; It is not an error. What you are saying to try is again the same thing as the question is...i.e You are trying to redefine a variable ..which is not allowed here!

Comment: thankyou friend for pointing ! That was a shortform though.. 'bcoz'  !!!
But edited for people like you who find difficult to understand simple words like that

Comment: The answer is correct, you can not reassign a member variable outside a method or static block. In this case the member variable is 'discriminant'